# emberjs transitionToRoute nested dynamic

Tags: dynamic, ember.js, routes

When I call the following :

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('dashboards.submenu',  {dashboard_id: "31", item_id: "97", subitem_id: "11"} );
```

I've also tried:

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('dashboards.submenu',  dash, item, subitem);
```

without success...

My url goes like this :

```
localhost:9000/#/dashboards/undefined/undefined/undefined
```

Unfortunately I would of like it to be

```
localhost:9000/#/dashboards/31/97/11
```

Any idea why?

If I go directly to

```
localhost:9000/#/dashboards/31/97/11
```

It works properly....

this is my router....

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("index",  { path: "/" });

    this.resource("dashboards",  { path: "/dashboards" } , function(){
               this.route("main", { path: '/' });
               this.route("index", { path: '/:dashboard_id' });
               this.route("submenu", { path: '/:dashboard_id/:item_id/:subitem_id' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement both `model` and `serialize` methods for your route. For example:

```
model: function(params) {
  return Ember.Object.create({dashboard_id: params.dashboard_id, item_id: params.item_id, subitem_id: params.subitem_id});
},

serialize: function(model) {
  return {dashboard_id: model.get('dashboard_id'), item_id: model.get('item_id'), subitem_id: model.get('subitem_id')};
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried the serialize / deserialize method without success... not it works... Even though, model dont have "get" method, I had to use  model.dashboard_id       , model.item_id, model.subitem_id